# Donut chart graph is being displayed within the single page html site?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

So I created a barchart and it was able to be displayed. I created a new component for donut chart. I was able to create the donut chart but for some reason it is not being displayed. I use angular and d3.js to create the charts. I checked the DOM and it is showing that it is there. [image: shows the DOM]

Here is the code for the data that will be passing in.

```
public data:any = 

 {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12};
```

I checked my code and it should be parsing and drawing the donut chart but im not sure. I even used a debugger to figure out the issue. Here is my code:

```
private drawDonut(dataSet: any[]): void{
 let svg = d3.select('figure#donutChart').select('svg')
.append('svg')
.attr("width", this.width)
.attr("height", this.height)
.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + 
 this.height / 2 + ")");
 console.log(this.data)

  //creating the colors in the donut chart for the 
  different data values
 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(dataSet)
  .range(["#e7968b" , "#88b0ea" , "#66b447", "#744921 " , "#ffb02a"])

 const donut = d3.pie<any>()
  .value(d=>d[1]);
  //const sortedata =  Object.entries(dataSet).sort((a, b) 
=> Number(b[1]) - Number(a[1]))

 const dataInput = donut(Object.entries(dataSet))

// building the pie chart
  svg
  .selectAll('donutChart')
  .data(dataInput)
  .join('path')
  .attr('d', d3.arc<any>())
  .attr('fill', function(d: { data: string[]; }):any { 
   console.log("!!!!!!",d.data[1]); 
   return(color(d.data[1])) })
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
```

If someone can help explain whats wrong it'll be very helpful for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the SVG in another selected SVG, which doesn't exist:

```
let svg = d3.select('figure#donutChart').select('svg')
    .append('svg')
```

Thus, just remove the `select('svg'):

```
let svg = d3.select('figure#donutChart').append('svg')
```